# file_get_contents not working for local files

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I recently upgraded my XAMPP from PHP 5.2 to 5.3.1

I seem to be having a problem with file_get_contents().

I can use the function to get something like "http://www.google.com", but it times out when I use it on a domain I have setup locally e.g. "http://localhost/my_dir/my_css_file.css".

I'm not really sure what the problem is. If it's a bug, is there a viable alternative?

Kindly advise.

Comment: Can't you use relative paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by using CURL. Here's the code. It will work with remote files e.g. 
**http://yourdomain.com/file.ext**

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, ''.$file_path_str.'');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, sprintf("Mozilla/%d.0",rand(4,5)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$curl_response_res = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

I could not use @James solution because I'm using `ob_start` and `ob_flush` elsewhere in my code, so that would have messed things up for me.

Answer (score 6):

Try to use `include()` instead of `file_get_contents()`.

```
<?php include($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/my_dir/my_css_file.css"); ?>
```

or

```
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/my_dir/my_css_file.css"); ?>
```

---

Updates corresponding your comments:

```
$string = get_include_contents('somefile.php');

function get_include_contents($filename) {
    if (is_file($filename)) {
        ob_start();
        include $filename;
        $contents = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $contents;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This will get file data into variable `$string`.

Comment: I need to get this data into a variable that's why file_get_contents is essential. Not sure if I can do the same with include()?

Comment: @Chuck - Have you checked your file permissions?

Comment: @lgnatz - Nice variation on file_get_contents(), I like it.

Comment: This looks like it would work. Unfortunately, I have a separate ob_start() implementation going on with my page. I'm trying to see if I can work something out with CURL.

Comment: This doesn't work if the URL can only be accessed through an http request, e.g. a local Wordpress rss feed.

Answer (score 1):

Any chance you're on a Windows system?
There is a bug in a combination of Windows, file_get_contents and localhost which is not going to be fixed. See [Bug 38826](http://bugs.php.net/38826) and [Bug 40881](http://bugs.php.net/40881)

Try using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost or set up any different domain name. Then you should get it working.

Comment: Yes I'm on Windows. I'm actually not using localhost per se. I have a lot of domain names defined in my hosts file, and also in my apache.conf. So I can setup something like http://mydomain/myfiledir/myfile.css for example. Is there a workaround for this?!

Answer (score 0):

I recently solved this problem. On my windows machine it is acceptable to have spaces in your folder names. However PHP wasnt able to read this path.

I changed my folder name

From:

```
 C:\Users\JasonPC\Desktop\Jasons Work\Project
```

To:

```
 C:\Users\JasonPC\Desktop\JasonsWork\Project
```

Then PHP was able to read my files again.