# PHP open txt file and echo its contents

Tags: php

The path of my .txt file is `C:\Users\George\Desktop\test.txt`

And I use:

```
$path = "C:\\Users\\George\\Desktop\\test.txt";
$fileContent = file_get_contents($path);
echo $fileContent;
```

But I get `file_get_contents(C:\Users\George\Desktop\test.txt) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream`. But why?

Comment: `Failed to open stream` can mean a permissions issue as well

Comment: possible duplicate of [file\_get\_contents not working for local files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457692/file-get-contents-not-working-for-local-files)

Comment: Wrong assertion : "as the error mentions, that path exists..." php is just telling you there was an error opening that path, it doesn't mean it exists, also, the error should mention the reason, i.e.: `not found`, `permission denied`, etc..

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
$path = "C:/Users/George/Desktop/test.txt";
$fileContent = file_get_contents($path);
echo $fileContent;
```

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(C:/Users/George/Desktop/test.txt) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/a2133027/public_html/index.php on line 5

Comment: @darkchampionz Your server is in linux and you are trying to read a file in windows?

Comment: @darkchampionz no, they aren't, either php is running on a linux virtual machine on windows or a linux server.  This type of file structure `/home/a2133027/` is linux.

Comment: under windows path separator is \ , its only in URLs that you can use / even if the server is under windows ;)

Comment: But again how can I do the same on linux? I've tried $str = file_get_contents("C:\\Users\\George\\Desktop\\test.txt"); and din't work...

Comment: a way to personal files under linux is : `~/test.txt` maybe `~/Desktop/test.txt`

Answer (score 1):

> as the error mentions, that path exists...

Wrong assertion, PHP is just telling you there was an error opening that path, it doesn't mean it exists, also, the error message should mention the reason for the error, i.e.: `not found`, `permission denied`, etc...

---

## Answer:

Your code syntax is correct. The error is one of the following 3:

1 - The file doesn't exist.
2 - The path is wrong.
3 - Php doesn't have permission to access that file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if YOU do not have the right to read this file as PHP, the system have it, try exec or system :

```
$path = 'C:\\Users\\George\\Desktop\\test.txt';

function getFile_exec($path)
{
    if(file_exists($path))
    {
        return exec("cat $path");
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

function getFile_syst($path)
{
    if(file_exists($path))
    {
        return system("cat $path");
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

var_dump(getFile_exec($path));
var_dump(getFile_syst($path));
```

But as you have this error : `Warning: file_get_contents(C:/Users/George/Desktop/test.txt) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/a2133027/public_html/index.php on line 5` and like Pedro Lobito said, you must be on linux, so, the good way to access your files on desktop may be : `~/Desktop/test.txt` or `~/test.txt` if it's directly in your user files ... Are you sure, you are under windows ?

Comment: oh, maybe under windows its `type` and not `cat` i don't remember ... not using windows anymore ^^