# file_get_contents not working for local files, same issue with cURL

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

**The problem:**

`file_get_contents('http://google.com');` works fine (works for any external url)

`file_get_contents('http://my.server.org/existing_file.php');` returns nothing, and `var_dump($http_response_header);` returns an empty array when loading any local url.

I get the same empty response using 127.0.0.1 and localhost in place of the domain name.

**I've tried/checked:**

I've tried using `cURL` instead as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457692/file-get-contents-not-working-for-local-files) - I get the same result (works for external URLs, empty response for local).

`allow_url_fopen=On` and `cURL` is enabled in `php.ini` according to `phpinfo()` - this must be ok, as I can load external URLs without a hitch.

I cannot use `include` instead, as I need to load a URL with variables to pass to a PDF renderer. 
Is there some other php.ini setting that needs to change? Or could it be some other problem? I think it is a configuration issue because my code works fine locally in MAMP, but not on the production server.

**Why I am doing this at all:**

It's all tied up in a Wordpress `functions.php` file - I'm basically loading a url like `http://my.server.org/path/to/file/?pdf-template`, which I then check against the path to load the correct rendering template, which then feeds the *rendered* php to [DOMPDF](http://pxd.me/dompdf/www/examples.php) to generate a PDF file on the fly. Ultimately it means the client can append `/pdf/` to any url in their wordpress site and get a PDF version.

What's odd is that this used to work fine on their server, and the person in charge of the server at the client says nothing has changed with the configuration. They *have* changed webhost in the last month though, which probably has something to do with it.

***Update***

I managed to pull this from the error log

`Notice: file_get_contents(): send of 2 bytes failed with errno=104 Connection reset by peer in /home/path/to/my/file.php on line 19`

The problem also appears to be intermittent - *sometimes* `file_get_contents` works, sometimes it fails with the above error. There doesn't seem to be a pattern.

Could this be a firewall problem?

Comment: Try it with `real` path of file.Like this : `file_get_contents('/path/to/file/existing_file.php', true);`

Comment: I checked and found that `file_get_contents` worked. `cURL` did not.

Comment: @Mr.Engineer that works, but I can't use that unfortunately, as I have to pass some parameters - I'm loading a dynamic PHP page that renders HTML to feed to a PDF renderer

Comment: Please give an example, how do you want to pass the parameters and how do you want to use it.

Comment: @Mr.Engineer I've updated the question with more details

Comment: Please refer this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). Here you will get how to pass parameters in `file_get_contents` while using `real` path.  You can pass `pdf-template` as `POST` with the help of `stream_context_create()`.

Comment: I have this same issue exactly. Need to use the URL of the local wordpress website, not able to get the local path as it will require lots of work and wordpress puts them in dated folders.

Comment: Same problem. WordPress + a page that requires parameters + DomPDF, I also cannot get those functions to work for local URLs, only external.